# Add a line to a 2D density plot using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is 2D density plot from Hadley Wickham's book:

```
f2d <- with(faithful, MASS::kde2d(eruptions, waiting, 
                                  h = c(1, 10), n = 50))
df <- with(f2d, cbind(expand.grid(x, y), as.vector(z)))
names(df) <- c("eruptions", "waiting", "density")
erupt <- ggplot(df, aes(waiting, eruptions, fill = density)) +
   geom_tile() +
   scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
   scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
erupt + scale_fill_gradient(limits = c(0, 0.04), low = "white", high = "black")
```

[image]

I try to plot a line on top of this:

```
mydf <- data.frame(x=c(50,60,70),y=c(2,3,4))
erupt + scale_fill_gradient(limits = c(0, 0.04), low = "white", high = "black") + geom_line(aes(x=x,y=x), data = mydf)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(x = c(50, 60, 70), y = c(50, 60, 70), fill = function (x,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 0
```

I don't understand why this is. Thank you.

Comment: You set `fill` globally in `ggplot` and `geom_line` can't find the variable *density* in `mydf`.  Among other things, you can add `inherit.aes = FALSE` to `geom_line`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems, first as @aosmith says you need to set density specific to the aesthetic in geom_tile.  secondly there's a typo in `geom_line(aes(x=x,y=x)`

So

```
erupt <- ggplot(df, aes(waiting, eruptions)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill=density)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))

mydf <- data.frame(x=c(50,60,70),y=c(2,3,4))
erupt + scale_fill_gradient(limits = c(0, 0.04), low = "white", high = "black") + 
  geom_line(aes(x=x,y=y), data = mydf)
```

Produces

[image]

Comment: I didn't realise ggplot sets global features. That makes a lot more sense now thanks.